# How to find all branches in git which are earlier than provided?

Tags: git

How can I find all branches which are earlier than provided in git?
For example, I have master -> v1 -> v2 and master -> v3(created after v1 and v2), so I would like to get v1 and v2.

Comment: Please explain more about what you want to accomplish here. Are you asking for all branches that have not been merged into a specific branch/commit?

Comment: I have many 'version' branches from master for every version V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, which all was merged into master. Also there are a lot of feature branches from every 'version' branch. We have active development in V4 and in V5 and we merge them in master periodically, V1, V2, V3 - done, so we would like to remove all branches that was created before V4(V1, V2, V3 and all corresponding feature branches)

Comment: So again, you want to find all branches that have not been merged into V4?

Comment: What do you mean by "earlier than provided"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `git branch -a --contains SHA` or `git tag --contains SHA`, where SHA is any valid commit identifier. You will receive all branches and tags that contains required changes.

To clear all merged branches, you could use `git branch -a --merged` in current `HEAD`. So, if you want to check all merged branches into the `master`, then you should checkout `master` branch and execute given command.